# validity or invalidity in this case?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

The sentence is,

> ```
> We shall apply (2) to the realistic model, regardless of the validity of this formula when x is small.
> ```

The situation is that, for the realistic model, the formula (2) is invalid when x is small.

So, should the 'validity' be replaced by 'invalidity'?

Answer (score 1):

*Validity (statistics) is the **extent** to which a concept, conclusion or measurement is well-founded and corresponds accurately to the real world.* (Wikipedia)

So how valid is something, is how much corresponds accurately to reality. So, regardless of how much (2) corresponds accurately to reality when x is small, you shall apply it.

You **need not** replace "validity" with "invalidity" in your sentence, it is correct the way it is.

Had we not been talking about mathematics, your sentence should probably make more sense when validity (state of being acceptable/logical/true) had indeed been replaced with invalidity (state of being unaccetable/illogical/false).